# PHP .ics file download fails

Tags: php, file, download

My ics creator fails when it comes to download the created file.
I've tried the following:

```
function createICS($start, $end, $type, $hrStart, $hrEnd){
$filename = $hrStart."-".$hrEnd." ".$type.".ics";
$string=" 
BEGIN:VCALENDAR 
VERSION:2.0 
PRODID:PHP 
METHOD:REQUEST 
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:".$start." 
DTEND:".$end."
DESCRIPTION:".$type." 
SUMMARY:".$type." vom ".$hrStart." bis zum  ".$hrEnd."
UID:1
SEQUENCE:0 
DTSTAMP:".date('Ymd')."T".date('His')." 
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR 
"; 
/*!$handle = fopen($filename, 'W');
fwrite($handle, $string);
fclose($handle)*/

/*header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Length: ". filesize($filename).";");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; "); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");*/

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($filename) . "\"");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));
header("Connection: close");

echo $string;
```

}

But I get just this response instead of the .ics file:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Can someone help me?

Thanks

Yanick

Comment: The headers you used are probably getting overridden by the PHP warning about filesize().  You also probably want `strlen($string)` instead of `filesize($filename)` because $filename isn't a real file.

Comment: well after replace `filesize($filename)` with `strlen($string)` there is no longer an error, but the string got put out like an normal echo... Maybe it's because the icalcreator.php is called by an jQuery post?
`$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "iCal.php",
data: {
"startDate": multiDateArray[i],
"endDate": multiDateArray[i+1],
"type": multiDateArray[i+2],
"hrStartDate": multiDateArray[i+3],
"hrEndDate": multiDateArray[i+4]
}
});`

Comment: Ah yes you won't be able to download the file that way.  If you don't mind using GET instead of POST, you can set window.location to a URL that will call your function instead.  If you want to use POST, this answer may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/9970672/1636812

Comment: Thanks for the cool link, worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Brian Adams said, relplacing `filesize($filename)` with `strlen($string)`solved the problem.